# Why Inserting only last line of csv to dynamodb from csv

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

data.csv is below

```
20,ABC,PC
21,DEF,PC
22,Aka,PC
23,Vee,PC
```

Code is below

```
import boto3
import csv

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    s3_file_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    resp = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name,Key=s3_file_name)
    data = resp['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
    print (data)
    employees = data.split("\n")
    print (employees)
    for emp in employees:
          emp_data = emp.split(',')
          print (emp_data)
    table = dynamodb.Table('employees')
    try:
        table.put_item(
        Item = {"emp_id":emp_data[0],
         "Name":emp_data[1],
         "Company":emp_data[2]
     })
    except Exception as e:
        print ('endof file')
    return 'file uploaded'
```

After running the code dynamodb got inserted only the last line `23,Vee,PC`

Dynamodb has `emp_id` as the primary key. it is supposed to insert 4 keys and values to dynamodb

Comment: Your call to `table.put_item` is outside of your `for` loop, so it's only being called once with the last item the loop iterated over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust your code to look like this

```py
import boto3
import csv

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    s3_file_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    resp = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name,Key=s3_file_name)
    data = resp['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
    employees = data.split("\n")
    table = dynamodb.Table('employees')
    for emp in employees:
        emp_data = emp.split(',')
        print (emp_data)

        try:
            table.put_item(
                Item = {
                    "emp_id": emp_data[0],
                    "Name": emp_data[1],
                    "Company": emp_data[2]
                }
            )
        except Exception as e:
            print ('endof file')
    return 'files saved to Dynamodb'
```

However you're probably better off using the [batch_write_item](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.batch_write_item) to write multiple items to your table